# Modifying elements in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapper

I have a weird question.. 
I use bootstrap for the first time and it's very awesome indeed. While coding my test website, I figured out something wrong in the monitor sizing.. and that's:

-I copied the navigation html code directly to new line
-I removed the hamburger icon for the switch toggle -show / dont show- from the second new created icon
-I modified the main content for the current element
-whenever I force small the monitor like alternativly telling the site I open from a small monitor, the second bar's element completely disappear. and since I already deleted the toggle button, I can't activate it nor doing anything but maximizing the size so it appears again.

The thing is, i want it to be completely appeared. No toggle thing, only compressing itself when its previewed from small monitor just like the navigation bar when I click on the hamburger icon

Any thoughts how to do this? Thanks and sorry for my awful annoying question. I know it's very annoying but, I just started learning this language and I may face some things in the process.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sidebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbarmain navbar navbar-default mainnav">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">S-Bolb</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Feed <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Add Page</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Manage Pages</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Trending</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">co.Groups</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Find Friends</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="userpanel">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Ahmed T.</a>
                    </li>
                    <a href="#">Senior Designer</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="#">View my profile</a>
                    <br>
                    <a>1</a>-<a>2</a>-<a>3</a>-<a>4</a>-<a>5</a>
                    <br>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <a href="#">Connected Networks</a>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook /username</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter /username</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Instagram /username</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tumblr /username</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Behance /username</a>
                    </li>
                    <a href="#">add more</a>
                </ul>
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Liked Pages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">App Center</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Games Feed</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Customize Profile</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Social Groups</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Group 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Group 2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">My Account</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Advertising</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class="block-button" href="#">Logout</a>
            </div>
            <!-- feed -->
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <nav class="usercontrolbar navbar navbar-default">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                            <li class="active"><a href="#">view all <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">close friends (3) <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li><a href="#">Suzan William</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Boza Suman</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Cameron Wheeler</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="dropdown">
                                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">custom category (15) <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Group</a>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                            <li><a style="font-size:22px;">Welcome back, Ahmed!  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left" id="menu-toggle" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                                            </li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.container-fluid -->
                            </nav>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/geometryangle.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Menu toggle script -->
    <script>
        $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and the sidebar.css:

```
.row{
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}

#wrapper {
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
    height: 100%
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-right: -200px;
    right: 70px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #222;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#wrapper.active {
    padding-right: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    right: 150px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar_menu li a, .sidebar-nav li a {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 150px;
    background: #252525;
    border-top: 1px solid #373737;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
    -webkit-transition: background .5s;
    -moz-transition: background .5s;
    -o-transition: background .5s;
    -ms-transition: background .5s;
    transition: background .5s;
}
.sidebar_name {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .7;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
  text-indent: 20px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #999999;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.choixMenu{

 font-size: 12px;
 float: right;
 text-align-right;
 margin-right: 1px;

}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

#main_icon
{
    float:right;
   padding-right: 65px;
   padding-top:20px;
}
.sub_icon
{
    float:right;
   padding-right: 65px;
   padding-top:10px;
}
.content-header {
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
}

.content-header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 20px;
  line-height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    #wrapper {
    padding-right: 70px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    right: 70px;
}
#wrapper.active {
    padding-right: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
    right: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
}
```

The second thing is:
How can I make the border sharp? Whenever I add new rule in CSS for all the layout to be with no border, it doesn't work, why is it soft from the edges and not completely 90 degree?

Comment: Please send a link of jsfiddle or similar sites where I can check your page correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the **second** question:

To make the corners of your `navbar` you need to add the `.navbar-static-top` class like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <!-- enter code here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reinstalling the css file to get the toggle functions back.
Once you have that, within the Bootstrap CSS file, you can change when the Toggle function activates, this gives you the option to call the toggle on a certain screen-size.

**second**question, you can either set the navbar-default/inverse to navbar-static-top, or if you want it to stick to the top, change the CSS to `border-radius:0px !important`

Hope this helps